# Is there a way to disable file sharing via apple-id?

Tags: apple-id, sharing, smb, file-sharing, afp

In High Sierra connecting to a mac using an older OS (el capitan), I see the default connection is using the appleid for authentication (showing `Connected as: com.apple.idms.appleid.prd...`). Is there a way to disable this and only allow sharing with a locally generated user account password? I know I can choose to connect with my local password on a per-case basis, but I want to disable the ability to connect with appleid entirely, as I feel it is less secure to allow this.

I see there are [other questions that seem somewhat related](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/220579/prevent-file-sharing-access-with-apple-id), but this is not exactly what I am asking--which is how to disable this entirely without deleting the apple id from the user account.